# Tomcat 6 behind HAproxy 2, show only a white page

Tags: tomcat, haproxy

I am having quite a fight with a Tomcat 6 (on CentOS 7.6) which is behind a HAproxy 2 (on CentOS 7.7), maybe someone can help me.

I want my users to put on the web browser something like http://myapp.mydomain.com this will resolve HAProxy IP, where it will be taken and forwarded to http://TomcatIP:Port/some/path/tofile (single server in the back end, no balancing yet).
It seems to be configured correctly, because when I put the simple URL on the web browser, the favicon and title of myapp appear, but the rest of the page is kept blank (white with nothing on it, no error, nothing).
I know there are other ways to accomplish this without involving HAProxy, but this is a prove of concept, to start using it as a frontend for more sites and using loadbalancing.

This is my HAProxy.cfg:

```
 #  HAProxy  configuration file   #

 global
     maxconn 5000
     log /dev/log local0
     user haproxy
     group haproxy

defaults
     log global
     mode http
     option  log-health-checks
     option  log-separate-errors
     option  dontlog-normal
     option  dontlognull
     option httplog
     option  socket-stats
     retries 5
     maxconn 5000
     option redispatch


#             Front-ends            #

frontend MY_APP
     bind IP:80
     acl is_myapp hdr(Host) -i myapp.mydomain.com
     use_backend backend_myapp if is_myapp

 #           Back-ends               #

 backend backend_myapp
         http-request set-path /myapp/path/tofile
         server myapp IP:Port cookie myapp check
```

Do not know where to go from here, any help will be much appreciated.
Sorry if my english level is off!

Adding some information:

I proceed to turn on the haproxy log, and found a bunch of 404 lines after the initial connection (which is the only line with a 200 OK) when the proxy goes to the server to look for different components of the page. I will paste some lines so you can see:

```
May  7 17:57:43 localhost haproxy[6642]: 192.168.18.175:58170 [07/May/2020:17:57:43.502] myapp backend_myapp/myapp 5/0/2/3/10 200 3039 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
May  7 17:57:43 localhost haproxy[6642]: 192.168.18.175:58170 [07/May/2020:17:57:43.513] myapp backend_myapp/myapp 198/0/2/3/203 404 1269 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /myapp/static/Shared/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css?144580 HTTP/1.1"
May  7 17:57:43 localhost haproxy[6642]: 192.168.18.175:58171 [07/May/2020:17:57:43.862] myapp backend_myapp/myapp 2/0/1/3/6 404 1231 - - ---- 6/6/1/1/0 0/0 "GET /myapp/static/gxui/gxui-all.css?188160 HTTP/1.1"
May  7 17:57:43 localhost haproxy[6642]: 192.168.18.175:58172 [07/May/2020:17:57:43.862] myapp backend_myapp/myapp 3/0/1/3/7 404 1275 - - ---- 6/6/2/2/0 0/0 "GET /myapp/static/Resources/Spanish/WorkWithPlusTheme.css?1848857 HTTP/1.1"
May  7 17:57:43 localhost haproxy[6642]: 192.168.18.175:58175 [07/May/2020:17:57:43.865] myapp backend_myapp/myapp 5/0/1/4/10 404 1223 - - ---- 6/6/2/2/0 0/0 "GET /myapp/static/gxtimezone.js?70721 HTTP/1.1"
May  7 17:57:43 localhost haproxy[6642]: 192.168.18.175:58174 [07/May/2020:17:57:43.862] myapp backend_myapp/myapp 6/0/2/4/12 404 1279 - - ---- 6/6/1/1/0 0/0 "GET /myapp/static/scaMessage/css/jquery.pnotify.default.css?16960 HTTP/1.1"
May  7 17:57:43 localhost haproxy[6642]: 192.168.18.175:58173 [07/May/2020:17:57:43.863] myapp backend_myapp/myapp 6/0/1/6/13 404 1253 - - ---- 6/6/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /myapp/static/scaMessage/css/jquery-ui.css?16960 HTTP/1.1"
```

This is what I see, on the tomcat server access-log:

```
10.2.0.40 [07/May/2020:19:55:15 -0300] GET /myapp/path/tofilemyapp/static/gxcfg.js?70721 HTTP/1.1 404 1043 51E30637266E0CBD1A2488F384378CE6 http-8080-17 1
10.2.0.40 [07/May/2020:19:55:15 -0300] GET /myapp/path/tofilemyapp/static/Shared/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js HTTP/1.1 404 1095 51E30637266E0CBD1A2488F384378CE6 http-8080-17 2
10.2.0.40 [07/May/2020:19:55:15 -0300] GET /myapp/path/tofilemyapp/static/Shared/ext/ext-all.js HTTP/1.1 404 1069 51E30637266E0CBD1A2488F384378CE6 http-8080-17 1
10.2.0.40 [07/May/2020:19:55:17 -0300] GET /myapp/path/tofilemyapp/static/gxui/gxui-all.js HTTP/1.1 404 1059 51E30637266E0CBD1A2488F384378CE6 http-8080-17 1
10.2.0.40 [07/May/2020:19:55:17 -0300] GET /myapp/path/tofilemyapp/static/messages.spa.js?70721 HTTP/1.1 404 1057 51E30637266E0CBD1A2488F384378CE6 http-8080-17 1
10.2.0.40 [07/May/2020:19:55:17 -0300] GET /myapp/path/tofilemyapp/static/login.js?2019112512435781 HTTP/1.1 404 1043 51E30637266E0CBD1A2488F384378CE6 http-8080-17 1
10.2.0.40 [07/May/2020:19:55:17 -0300] GET /myapp/path/tofilemyapp/static/Shared/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js HTTP/1.1 404 1093 51E30637266E0CBD1A2488F384378CE6 http-8080-17 1
```

As you can see by know, the problem is that, for every request that the proxy makes to the server it appends the /myapp/path/tofile part, so the server does not find the files.
Is there a way to fix this? I wanto to redirec to /myapp/path/tofile only the first request, when the client enters to http://myapp.mydomain.com

Thanks again

Comment: Side note - any particular reason to use Tomcat 6? Last I knew, at least 9.0.X was current.

Comment: the usual, the app was developed quite a time ago, there is no intention (from management) to start a project for migrating this to a newer plataform.

Comment: I strongly suggest turning on the access log in Tomcat - then you could perhaps see the requests come in but have a wrong path, or something else that leads you to more info

Comment: Will look into that and let you know if I find anything

Comment: Is the tomcat configured to answer to the host myapp.mydomain.com?

Comment: @Aleksandar the server does not have any particular configuration, server.xml is I believe intact from installation. If I modify the host file on my PC, so myapp.mydomain.com resolves the tomcat server IP (not passing through the proxy) the page loads normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way arround it, instead of a rewrite (set-path), I went for a redirect, and change the frontend in this way:

```
frontend myapp *:80
        acl is_gesa hdr(Host) -i myapp.mydomain.com
        redirect location /myapp/path/tofile if { path / }
        use_backend backend_myapp if is_myapp
```

(this could be done on the backend as well, but i want to keep the backend as clean as possible - for some reason)

Thanks to everyone for the kind help!